# How to change the Java path in firewall settings to a different version of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft LAN wasn't working so I searched the issue and allowed Java through the firewall however the path goes to a different folder for the game I have on my computer and when I click 'change settings' inside the window to allow apps through the firewall the text box with the java path can't be edited. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi Evo, I realize this is directly related to being able to play Minecraft, but questions of this type (editing your firewall configuration) are off-topic here. Try asking this at [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks after changing firewall settings.